# error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype OnCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: java, methods, overriding, implementation, oncreateoptionsmenu

```
@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
            finish();
            return true;
    }
```

I have a error message when i build on AndroidStudio : error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
I need help

Comment: It is a lowercase 'o' in onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those methods have a lower case 'o'

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); return true; } 


@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 switch (item.getItemId()){ 
case R.id.logout:
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class)); finish(); return true; }
```